# Grub rescue mode after deleting kali linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, repair

I have a Windows 10 PC where Kali Linux was installed as a dual boot. I deleted the Kali partition from computer management. After I rebooted my PC, I got GRUB rescue mode > unknown filesystem.

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
```

I tried that with all my partitions and got `unknown filesystem` every time.

How do I fix this?

I don't have a Windows CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions below,

1. Use another computer to download a eval copy of windows from [Technet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/)
2. Either use a DVD or a USB flash drive to make bootable media.

   A. If using a DVD, burn the downloaded iso to the dvd using a tool like  [IMGBurn](https://ninite.com/imgburn). [Here's a videotutorial](https://youtu.be/eCRCPWhhxpo?t=1m47s)

   B. If using a USB flash drive then download [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.9.exe) select the iso and click start. [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/VmtRE9LTCOE?t=1m51s)
3. Boot your computer up using the newly created media, depending on your pc you may have to change a setting in the BIOS or press a key on startup to boot from the usb drive.
4. Once it has loaded up click "Next"
   [image: IMG1]
5. Now click "Repair Your Computer"
   [image: IMG2]
6. Then Select "Troubleshoot"
   [image: IMG3]
7. Now Select "Advanced Options"
   [image: IMG4]
8. Finally Select "Startup Repair"
   [image: IMG5]

Let it run through and should be able to boot into Windows 10.

If the above does not work, Resuming from step 7 above.

8. Start by selecting command prompt.
   [image: IMG6]
9. Now select an account you have access to or your account (this account must be an administrator), and enter the accounts password then click continue.
   [image: IMG7]

[image: IMG8]

10. You will now be at an elevated command prompt type in the the bold lowercase text below.
    [image: IMG9]

    diskpart
    list disk
    list part

You will now see one of two layouts this will determine how we proceed so make sure you follow the correct instructions.

#### Layout A (UEFI):

We know that this is a UEFI install because of DISK 0 (The Disk That Windows is installed on) is GPT and their are four partitions on that disk.

[image: IMG10]

#### Layout B (BIOS/MBR)

We know that this is a BIOS/MBR disk because it's not GPT and it only has two partitions.
[image: IMG11]

#### Instructions for Layout A:

If you have this start by deleting partitions 1,2, and 3 BE CARFUL NOT TO DELETE PART 4 OR WHICH EVER ONE IS THE BIGGEST USUALLY BOOT PARTITIONS ARE NO BIGGER THAN 1GB.

Use the command to delete the partitions

```
sel part 1
del part override
```

Repeat this for partitions 1-3

You should now have this.
[image: IMG12]

Now type the following:

```
Create partition efi size=100
Format fs=fat32 label=”SYSTEM” quick
Assign letter=S
Create partition msr size=128
Exit

bcdedit C:\Windows /s S:

exit
```

You Should be all set.

#### MBR Instructions

This is even simpler.

Type the following:

```
Sel part 1
del part override
Create partition primary size=300
Format fs=ntfs label=”SYSTEM” quick
Assign Letter=S
active
exit

bcdboot C:\Windows /s S:
exit
```

That's it whether your on MBR/BIOS or UEFI you should now be able reboot and access Windows if not then there may be an error with your hard disk.